# Capture bitmap of ARCore ArSceneView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, arcore

I am trying to add a screenshot button that captures a screenshot of the ARCore camera view including the attached node.

I have tried several different approaches, all are able to capture the other content on the screen however the ARSceneView is always transparent.

Things I have tried:

```java
ArFragment arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
View view = arFragment.getARSceneView(); //Also tried arFragment.getView();
```

(1)

```java
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

(2)

```java
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(view);

public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null)
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

I also know that you can get an Image from the ARFragment, but it returns a blank transparent image

```java
Image image = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().acquireCameraImage();
//image is completely transparent and wrong size
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PixelCopy.request()

```
ArSceneView view = fragment.getArSceneView();
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, (copyResult) -> {
  if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
    // Save bitmap
  } else {
      // Error
  }
}, handler);
```

[Source](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sceneform-intro/#15)

Comment: PixelCopy sucks because it includes view widgets that are also visible over the ArSceneView (i.e. the screenshot button!!). I've tried `frame?.acquireCameraImage()` but that DOESN'T include 3D objects at all. How does one take a screenshot *with* 3D objects and *without* the screenshot button ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere no it doesn't capture the whole view hierarchy, only the `SurfaceView` content.

Comment: you are right! I am surprised because I had such a hard time with it yesterday. Weird

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @GovindPrajapati there was no problem. I think initially I gave it the wrong view - possibly the root view of the layout without noticing.

Comment: how do I take a screenshot without the AR objects?